# Rails testing, have a setup only for some tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

We are writing tests to a Rails application and we need to test a controller where we pass a header for almost every request, but not all.

You pass a header setting `@request.headers['my-header'] = 'my-header-content'`, but we only want to do this in some tests, not all, so having this line in `setup` is not an option, but we consider incorrect to have it repeated 20 or 30 times for every request made.

How could we achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `rspec`, you can separate them into two different context and then do a `before` for that context:

```
describe MyController do 
  context 'with specific header' do 
    before :all do 
      @request.headers['my-header'] = 'my-header-content'
    end
  end

  context 'other context' do
     #Tests without context
  end
end
```

If you're using `minitest` you can always separate your tests into classes. Then make one class to the specific header and another one to the other tests.